# Are Stack Overflow user identicons under copyright protection?

Tags: support, profile-picture

When you join Stack Overflow, if you do not provide your own user profile image, you get an automatically generated identicon.

My question is simple and quick: Are those identicons under copyright protection?

Comment: They’re called identicons.

Comment: https://github.com/stewartlord/identicon.js/blob/master/LICENSE (that's for the script that produces it, but I guess the output is even less prone to be licensed).

Comment: GitHub accounts use these too

Comment: I guess you want to use that icon also somewhere else.

Comment: @Trilarion Bingo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the identicons are automatically generated from user input (and I think that the output is even deterministic, so for the same email address you'll should get the same picture), I don't think automatic copyright protection is generally given to these "works", and I think that it's extremely unlikely SO Inc would ever pursue the protection of these images.

Nevertheless, the nuances of this are probably better asked about in law.se, where more knowledgeable users walk about.

A couple of links talking about this kind of thing:

- [Copyright in works generated by computer programs](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=5350b546-2fb3-440d-b496-3cd20af658e4)
- [Who holds the Copyright in AI Created Art](https://alj.artrepreneur.com/the-next-rembrandt-who-holds-the-copyright-in-computer-generated-art/)
- [French stance on intellectual property rights for content creatd[sic] by artificially intelligent entities](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45188/)